# Best practices for in scope of creating wrapper methods for Swal with preset configuration

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

I have such a class with such static methods.

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

export class AlertService {

  static errorMessage(title = 'Error', text = 'Error') {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: title,
      text: text
    })
  }

  static successMessage(title = 'Success', timer = 1500) {
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'success',
      title: title,
      timer: timer,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  }
}

export default AlertService;
```

I don't think the methods should be static. 
How is it right to implement such a class on best practices ?!

Comment: maybe I need to create a separate method for each alert?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't need to use the class.
Just use the function.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea 

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).